# Create dotted line

Tags: pdftex

**Code**

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\dashline{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\dabar@\dabar@\dabar@$}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

`\dashline` produces now a dashed line

\dashline

But a dotted vertical line is needed. Something like `\vdots` but e.g. with 5 dots

\vdots

\end{document}
```

**Purpose**

Create a vertical dotted line and not a dashed line.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\fivevdots{\vbox{\baselineskip1\p@ \lineskiplimit\z@
  \kern6\p@\hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$ a \vdots a \fivevdots a $
\end{document}
```